# How to make FTP transfer faster using powershell

Tags: powershell, ftp

I've implemented FTP upload using Powershell script and using .NET WebClient functionality.
However, it much slower than when I use let say GoFTP. Go FTP transfer file 4 times faster. However it doesn't have command line tool :(. Any suggestions, how to make FTP transfer faster?

Comment: I believe GoFTP opens more than one connection to the server.